# How can I call class into another class in css3?

Tags: html, css

I want to make an effect that would trigger my button transition when I hover the outer div box (parent) that already has its own transition. Can this be done with css or is it in need of some javascript?

My example:

```css
.box {
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 background: #eeeeee; 
 float: left;
 margin: 50px;
 -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
 transition: All 0.5s ease;
}
.box:hover {
 height: 350px;
}

#box_pic1 {
 background: url(http://nicholsd.com/_Media/image-15_med.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: relative;
 height: 196px;
 width: 262px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn_ani {
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
 opacity: 0.5;
 width: 150px;
 background: #99745c;
 border:1px solid #99745c;
 line-height: 35px;
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -ms-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;  
 position: absolute; 
 margin-left: 56px;
}

.btn_ani:hover {
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #99745c;
    opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.7s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.7s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.7s;
 -ms-transition: all ease 0.7s;
 transition: all ease 0.5s; 
 border:1px solid #99745c;
 margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">    
 <a href="www.google.com">
  <div id="box_pic1">
   <div class="btn_ani">View</div>
  </div>
 </a>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done with CSS. You could simply move the `:hover` state to the parent `.box` and the target the descendants like: `.box:hover .btn_ani`.

In this case elements can have their own `transition` value.

```css
.box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eeeeee; 
  float: left;
  margin: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.box:hover {
  height: 350px;
}

#box_pic1 {
  background: url(http://nicholsd.com/_Media/image-15_med.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: relative;
  height: 196px;
  width: 262px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn_ani {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 150px;
  background: #99745c;
  border:1px solid #99745c;
  line-height: 35px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  
  /* different transition from the parent */
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.7s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 0.7s;
  transition: all ease 0.7s;
  
  position: absolute; 
  margin-left: 56px;
}

.box:hover .btn_ani {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #99745c;
  opacity: 1; 
  border:1px solid #99745c;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">    
  <a href="www.google.com">
    <div id="box_pic1">
      <div class="btn_ani">View</div>
    </div>
  </a>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's so simple. Does it work on older browsers?

Comment: @Alex You;re welcome. If you mean the selector, yes, absolutely, it is well supported in legacy web browsers. But `transition` itself is not supported in IE <= 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you *would* like to try some jQuery, you could use a solution such as this:

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
    $('.btn_ani').toggleClass('margin');
});
```

With the css:

```
.margin{
    margin-top:80px;
}
```

[**and here is an example!**](http://jsfiddle.net/0bz3qf7q/2/)

Comment: That's not really going to work well if you have multiple instances of the `.box` class... which is pretty likely, I would think. If you're going to use jQuery, you'd probably at least want to use the `.parent()` method to make sure you're getting the right element.